# Stochastic dynamics of rotation intergral over $d\hat n$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, probability

I am looking into the stochastic dynamics of rotation in which we describe the orientation with a unit vector $\hat n$. If we let $p(\hat n',t)$ denote the probability that $\hat n=\hat n'$ at time $t$ then the mean value of $\hat n$ at $t$ is given by:
$$\int p(\hat n',t) \hat n' d\hat n'$$
Working in 3d - my question is should I interpret the integral over $d\hat n'$? Is it equivalent to an integral over solid angle? An explicit example would be useful.

Comment: For anyone who happens to stumble on this question; I found a good resource is: Dhont, 1996 "*An Introduction to Dynamics of Colloids*" pg$\sim$218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally express $\hat n$ using spherical coordinates and then consider the average of the angles:

$$\hat n = (\sin \theta \cos \phi,\sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta) = n_1 \hat x + n_2 \hat y + n_3 \hat z $$

The integral over $\hat n$ is therefore replaced by an integral over $\theta$ and $\phi$, which is just an integral over the solid angle.

For a general quantity $Q$, you have

$$\langle Q (\theta, \phi) \rangle_{\theta, \phi} = \int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi \int_0^{\pi}  p(\theta,\phi) \ Q(\theta,\phi)\  \sin \theta d \theta$$

The average values of the components of $\hat  n$ are

$$\langle n_1 \rangle= \int_0^{2 \pi}\cos \phi d \phi \int_0^{\pi} p(\theta,\phi) \cdot \sin^2 \theta d \theta$$

$$\langle n_2 \rangle= \int_0^{2 \pi}\sin \phi d \phi \int_0^{\pi} p(\theta,\phi) \cdot \sin^2 \theta d \theta$$

$$\langle n_3\rangle = \int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi \int_0^{\pi} p(\theta,\phi) \cdot \sin \theta \cos \theta d \theta$$

In case the distribution is uniform, then

$$p(\theta, \phi) = \frac 1 {4 \pi}$$

In this case, $\langle n_{1,2,3} \rangle = 0$.